# Cannot connect to Cassandra running in a Docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra

For my application, there is a Docker container `database` which runs Cassandra. I expose the ports `9160` and `9042` to the host machine, but for some reason, I cannot connect to Cassandra from my host. I am able to connect to it from other Docker containers using `cqlsh` **only if** I put the other container in the same network.

My `docker-compose` file (which I run with `docker-compose up`):

```yaml
  database:
    image: cassandra
    container_name: database
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
      - 9160:9160
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true
      - CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=database
    entrypoint: "/code/scripts/cassandra.sh"

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: driver/
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    network_mode: service:database
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVER=kafka:9092
      - CASSANDRA_HOST=localhost
    entrypoint: "/code/scripts/frontend.sh"
```

where `cassandra.sh` and `frontend.sh` simply initialise the database by running a script, and installing some packages respectively.

Using the above setup, I am able to use cqlsh by simply calling `cqlsh` in the `frontend` container. If, however, I remove the line `network_mode: service:database` from `frontend`, and try to connect using `cqlsh database` or `cqlsh $CASSANDRA_HOST`, even after I set `CASSANDRA_HOST=database`. Doing any of the aforementioned commands gives me:

`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.27.0.5:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('172.27.0.5', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`.

As a result, I am not able to run `cqlsh` from my host machine either, even though I exposed the port 9042. The host machine is a 2020 iMac running macOS Monterey 12.3.1.:

```sh
> netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/'
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
tcp46      0      0  *.29092                *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    911      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9042         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   7099      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.7000         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   7099      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54196        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   7099      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.7199         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   7099      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    911      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp46      0      0  *.7077                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    911      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp46      0      0  *.4040                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    911      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp46      0      0  *.9160                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    911      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp46      0      0  *.9042                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    911      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp46      0      0  *.2181                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    911      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.6463         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   1241      0 0x0100 0x00000106
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.49390        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    826      0 0x0100 0x00000106
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.45623        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    826      0 0x0100 0x00000106
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.49380        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    826      0 0x0100 0x00000106
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.49379        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    826      0 0x0100 0x00000106
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.15292        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    770      0 0x0000 0x0000020f
tcp6       0      0  *.5000                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    465      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  *.5000                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    465      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  *.7000                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    465      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  *.7000                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    465      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  *.49198                *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    494      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  *.49198                *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    494      0 0x0100 0x00000006
```

I've spent hours looking for a solution for this and have viewed nearly every possible post on StackOverflow and other sites on this topic, but none of the solutions work for me. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you using the official Cassandra Docker image?  The reference page on DockerHub might help: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra

Comment: Hi @Aaron, yes I am using the official one. ``image: cassandra`` seems to forward me to the same link you posted.

Comment: What are you using as the host system?  Docker Desktop?  If you're using Minkube or some other K8s based product, you might have to run a `kubectl -- port-forward service/cassandra 9042:9042`, depending on your service name.

Comment: I’m simply running it on Docker Desktop, correct. I’m not using Kubernetes.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the `docker` command that you're using?

Comment: Ah, I thought I already included it, my apologies. I edited the post.

Comment: So, this might sound silly, but your netstat says it's listening on `127.0.0.1.9042`.  Try connecting to that, once.

Comment: I tried that as well, but nothing happened (or rather, it wouldn't let me connect to that). I have actually found out what the problem is and posted the answer. Thank you a lot for your help though, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by setting the entrypoint:

```yaml
entrypoint: "/code/scripts/cassandra.sh"
```

As it turns out, some Cassandra settings are only initialised by the image if no entrypoint is provided. If one is provided, you must set these settings yourself, which I didn't do. I added the entrypoint `cassandra.sh` because I wanted to initialise the database by running a file `create.cql`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cassandra -R

# Wait for Cassandra to start up
while ! cqlsh -e 'describe cluster' ; do
    sleep 1
done

echo "Cassandra has started"

cqlsh --file '/code/scripts/create.cql'

echo "Cassandra has been initialised"

tail -f /dev/null
```

I ended up creating another Docker container that simply initialises the database once the database has started up:

```yaml
database:
  image: cassandra
  container_name: database
  depends_on:
    - kafka
  ports:
    - 9042:9042
    - 9160:9160
  volumes:
    - ./:/code

db_seeder:
  container_name: db_seeder
  build:
    context: db_seeder/
  depends_on:
    - database
  volumes:
    - ./:/code
  environment:
    - CASSANDRA_HOST=database
  entrypoint: "/code/scripts/cassandra.sh"
```

Comment: Excellent!  I’m glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The command **"docker pull cassandra:latest"** is utilizing Docker, a containerization platform, to download the latest version of the Cassandra database management system (DBMS) image from the official Docker Hub repository. In technical terms:

**Docker:** A platform that enables developers to package applications and their dependencies into lightweight, portable containers. Containers provide a consistent environment across different environments, making it easier to deploy and scale applications.

**pull:** This Docker command is used to fetch container images from a container registry. In this case, it's pulling the Cassandra image.

**cassandra:latest:** Specifies the image to be pulled. "cassandra" is the name of the Docker image for the Cassandra DBMS, and ":latest" indicates that the latest available version of the image should be retrieved.

**Docker Hub:** A cloud-based registry service where Docker users can share and access container images. The official Cassandra image is hosted on Docker Hub.

So, when you run **"docker pull cassandra:latest,"** Docker will download the most recent version of the Cassandra image from Docker Hub, making it available for local use on your machine.
docker pull cassandra:latest

Now for the command:

docker run --name cassandra -p 127.0.0.1:9042:9042 -p 127.0.0.1:9160:9160   -d cassandra

The command you provided is a Docker command used to run a Cassandra container. Let's break it down in technical terms:

**docker run:** This command is used to create and start a new container based on a specified image.

**--name cassandra:** Assigns the name "cassandra" to the newly created container. This is helpful for referencing the container in subsequent Docker commands.

**-p 127.0.0.1:9042:9042:** Maps the container's port 9042 (Cassandra's native transport port) to the host machine's port 9042. This means you can access Cassandra on the host machine at 127.0.0.1:9042.

**-p 127.0.0.1:9160:9160:** Maps the container's port 9160 (used for Thrift communication) to the host machine's port 9160. This allows you to interact with Cassandra using Thrift on the host machine at 127.0.0.1:9160.

**-d:** Runs the container in the background (detached mode), allowing you to continue using the terminal.

cassandra: Specifies the name of the Docker image to use for creating the container. In this case, it's the Cassandra image.

So, when you run the command **"docker run --name cassandra -p 127.0.0.1:9042:9042 -p 127.0.0.1:9160:9160 -d cassandra,"** it starts a new Cassandra container with specified port mappings, making Cassandra accessible on the host machine at the provided ports.

Utilising this command will make the (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))

Exception to disappear like magic!

**How Connect to Cassandra CQL Shell ?**

artwellmamvura@Artwells-MacBook-Pro ~ % docker exec -it cassandra cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.1.0 | Cassandra 4.1.3 | CQL spec 3.4.6 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>